# Display unique text and button in nodes in a view in drupal 7

Tags: views

I have created a view listing 'invitation' nodes. When viewing each invitation on a full page, I have created a small block to allow people to RSVP to these invitations, but I would like to give them access to the button to RSVP directly from the view list.

Basically, if the user viewing the node in the list was invited to the event, something like this would show:

'You have been invited. RSVP here [button]'

Or if they have already RSVP'd:
'You are attending. Change your RSVP [button]'.

Any suggestions on how to do that?

A few more details:
- I created a custom module to handle the invitation process and form on a full view of the nodes. Details of invitations (who, where, when) are stored in a database.
- when the user is on the invitation in full view, i have created a block to display the RSVP form, adapting it to the status of the RSVP of the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the '[Views php](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_php)' module, which allows to use php code as the output of a field in Views. Basically, after installing and enabling the module, I went to the views that I wanted to modify and added a field called 'Global: PHP'.

In that field's settings, there are two areas of note:

- the 'value code': I obtained the status of the invitation by calling a function from one of my modules and saving it in a variable.
  example:

  ```
  $truc=invitation_status($data->nid);
  ```
- the 'output code': it is used to display the result. A simple echo of the data saved as a variable works:

  ```
  <?php
    echo $truc;
  ?>
  ```

You can of course generate php code to display a link or a button, etc... I hope this helps people.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure if there's a module for that. Is Flags enough? In basic, it has a 0 or 1 option: respond and already attending.

And how to distinct users? I presume, users are logged in. Add a role to give certain users the privelege to see the RSVP-button/block/whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't detail (yet) HOW you implemented the invitation part of it, i.e. to indicate which users are invited for which specific event. If I was to implement those invitations, I'd use the [Entity Reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference) module to implement "invitations".

Next I would use the [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) module (not Flags ...) to allow invited people to "flag" such invitation node like "Yes, I would like to attend".

Once you'd have this in place, display the flag in your views, and from there those who are invited, could then just indicate via that "flag" that they want to attend.

Since the question is a bit vague about how your current view is constructed (consider adding a screenprint of the Vieuws UI to your question ...), it could well be that this needs to further refined with some extra "conditions", which you could pretty sure add to it using he [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module.

If you edit your question to be more specific, add moore details, then I can probably also furhter refine my answer here.