# How to implement RSVP Functionality?

Tags: flags, 7

I have created event using Calendar in [Drupal Commons](https://www.drupal.org/project/commons). I need to implement RSVP for these events Details like FB event section.

Kindly guide me to create RSVP plugin in Drupal Commons. I just searched the web to get some reference link for [RSVP Implementation in Drupal 7](https://www.drupal.org/node/2490724). In that link, user *nicoz* commented **"Use the [flag module](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) "**.

I just installed flag module and create that flag like **`Participant/Maybe/No`**, but I cannot achieve it, because a flag will only provide *flagged* content and *unflagged* content.

[image: Flag And UnFlag content]

Kindly give me any idea for this type of flag creation or else give me alternative module for  RSVP functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A flag that is created with the [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) module is indeed a boolean variable (it is "on" of "off"). In this specific case you should implement 3 possible values, i.e.:

- Participant
- Maybe
- No

Here is how you can get that implement by using 3 flags:

- Flag 1, with something like these "Link text" values:

  - (to **Flag**) = Yes I plan to participate.
  - (to **Unflag**) = Please ignore my "Yes I plan to participate" from before.
- Flag 2, with something like these "Link text" values:

  - (to **Flag**) = I'm not sure yet if I'll participate.
  - (to **Unflag**) = Please ignore my "I'm not sure yet if I'll participate" from before.
- Flag 3, with something like these "Link text" values:

  - (to **Flag**) = No I will not participate.
  - (to **Unflag**) = Please ignore my "No I will not participate" from before.

If it fits your requirement, you could "assume" that for somebody who did  NOT set Flag1 and did not set Flag 2, the default applies which is something like "user does not want to participate, or didn't bother to let us know about it". That will avoid you need Flag 3.

If you're not familiar enough with the [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) module yet, I strongly recommend watching the [set of 8 video tutorials](http://drupal.placeto.be/tutorial/learn-flag) about this module.

For more details, you may also want to refer to my answer to the question about [Display unique text and button in nodes in a view in drupal 7](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/165974/display-unique-text-and-button-in-nodes-in-a-view-in-drupal-7/165980#165980). It contains the details about using the [Entity Reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference) module for this, in combination with the [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) module, and possibly also the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module.

Comment: Nice explaination @Pierre.Vriens..i edit my question.But In flag module add under Node concept need to set flag variable and unflag variable..this two variable must required.How to set individual flag with individual values..Kindly give some idea or guide me in proper way..!!

Comment: I enhanced my answer (and added some interesting video links). Just for your information: From your screenprint I get the impression that you're trying to sqeeze 3 values in a single flag. That can impossibly work. If you want to use the Flag module (I think you should), you have to think with Yes/No or On/Off options ... Which will also lead to great options for creating interesting views of them all ...

Comment: Thanks @Pierre.vriens.. i tried to created flag concept using your idea.but need to list out participant list using that flag how can possible to achieve this..!!

Comment: I just create [another question for this participant list-out idea..](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/167749/how-to-list-out-flag-content-user-in-event-page-in-drupal-commons).Kindly go through it and give some idea this question also