# How Do i implement an alternative for the Privatemsg Bulkmail module?

Tags: 7

I'm using the modules [Private Message](https://www.drupal.org/project/privatemsg), [Invite](https://www.drupal.org/project/invite) and [Organic Groups](https://www.drupal.org/project/og) in [Drupal Commons](https://www.drupal.org/project/commons).

I get listed with trusted content using [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) and need to set private Message button for bulk operation just like the [Privatemsg Bulkmail](https://www.drupal.org/project/privatemsg_bulkmail) module from D6 (for which there is no D7 version yet).

How can I get the [Private Message](https://www.drupal.org/project/privatemsg) module to work with the [VBO](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) module, or any other module, in Drupal 7?

I created an Email system with bulk operation via external mail system.

> "User can invite friends and send email using [VBO module](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) "

But I want to send mail/message internal system like the Private Message system for bulk trusted contacts. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like there are [currently no plans](https://www.drupal.org/node/1363952#comment-5337342) for a D7 version of the [Privatemsg Bulkmail](https://www.drupal.org/project/privatemsg_bulkmail) module you are referring to. However, I'd use the [integration of the Privatemsg module with Rules](https://www.drupal.org/node/740366) instead (make sure to checkout this community docu, and its child pages ...), together with the [VBO](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) module.

For more details, refer to the video about [Using Rules components with VBO](http://drupal.placeto.be/tutorial/using-rules-components-with-vbo). Possibly you also want to look at the 2 prior videos and/or the 2 subsequent videos (all about [Views Bulk Operations](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations)), i.e.:

- [Introducing Views Bulk Operations](http://drupal.placeto.be/tutorial/introducing-views-bulk-operations).
- [More details about VBO settings](http://drupal.placeto.be/tutorial/more-details-about-vbo-settings).
- [Using Rules componens with more than one parameter](http://drupal.placeto.be/tutorial/using-rules-componens-with-more-than-one-parameter).
- [Using VBO to load list of objects into Rules](http://drupal.placeto.be/tutorial/using-vbo-to-load-list-of-objects-into-rules).

In this specific case;

- use [Views bulk operations](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) to create the list of your users to be targeted.
- use [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) action "Send a message" (provided by Privatemsg module).

PS: yet another great usage of the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module, in this case in combination with the [Privatemsg](https://www.drupal.org/project/privatemsg) module. So I wouldn't worry too much about the [Privatemsg Bulkmail](https://www.drupal.org/project/privatemsg_bulkmail) module not being available for D7.

Comment: Awesome Answer @Pierre.Vriens..Let me try it and update you..